# codenameone send JSON BODY in POST

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to use Codename One to send a POST request with a JSON BODY.
Here is the code that makes the connection and sends the message

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bOutput.write("{\"Key1\": \"Value1\",\"Key2\": \"Value2\"}".getBytes());  

    try {
        connectAction connReq = new connectAction();

        connReq.setPost(true);
        connReq.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "1234");
        connReq.addRequestHeader("client_id","4321");
        connReq.addRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        connReq.setUrl("https://myapi.com/test");
        connReq.setHttpMethod("POST");
        connReq.buildRequestBody(bOutput);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(connReq);
        Map<String,Object> result = new JSONParser().parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(connReq.getResponseData()), "UTF-8"));
        return result; 
    }
    catch(Exception err) {
        System.err.println(err);
        return null;
    }
```

And here is the derived class with the buildRequestBody Override

```
 public class connectAction extends ConnectionRequest
 {

    connectAction()
    {

    }



    @Override
    public void buildRequestBody(OutputStream os)
    {

    }
}
```

Now when I place a breakpoint at public void buildRequestBody(OutputStream os) I can see that 'os' has the value

os = (java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream) {"Key1": "Value1","Key2": "Value2"}

So I know that the value is making it all the way this far.

However when I launch the network monitor only the Request Header is populated and the header is empty.

Any help truly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following codes hope it will help

```
// convert the object to a JSON document
HashMap hashtable = new HashMap ();
hashtable.put("Key1", "Value1");
hashtable.put("Key2", "Value2");
final String payload = Result.fromContent(hashtable).toString();

protected void buildRequestBody(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    os.write(payload.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! I have really been struggling with this. I was about to change frameworks and look for something else :-). Thank you - Thank you!